# How to extract a matched substring from a String matching a pattern?

Tags: java

I am reading a String of either of the following pattern:

```
^<.*>.*</td>$
^<.*><.*>.*</a></td>$
```

Eamples:

```
<td nowrap valign="top" class="style1">Manhattan</td>
<td nowrap valign="top" class="style1"><a>New York</a></td>
```

I want to read `Manhattan` and `New York`

How can I write 2 Pattern.complie() methods in a same program? Matches() always returns true for my input lines, but after that how can I do the substring operation to extract `Manhattan` and `New York`? Any suggestion would of great help. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a parser?

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression like:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<td>(.+?)</td>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using GROUPS.

change  `^<.*>.*</td>$` to `^<.*>(?<name>.*)</td>$`

after matches() returns true you can extract name `matcher.group("name")` (returns string with your name).

**EDIT**
Thanks to Ian.

before java7 you'll have to do `matcher.group(1)`. Group `0`will give you the whole string matched.

Comment: Note that named groups require Java 7 - only numbered positional groups are supported by Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
String stem[] = "<td nowrap valign='top' class='style1'>Manhattan</td>".split(">");

String stem1[] = stemp[1].split("<");

System.out.println(stemp[0]);
```

is this you want?

Comment: String stem[] = "<td nowrap valign='top' class='style1'>Manhattan</td>".split(">");

String stem1[] = stem[1].split("<");
System.out.println(stem1[0]); try this this should exact print

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
public class tag {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputString="<td nowrap valign=top class=style1>Manhattan</td>"
                      +"<td nowrap valign=top class=style1><a>New York</a></td>";

       String noHTMLString = inputString.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
       System.out.println(""+noHTMLString);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you're using frameworks it's much easier... Selenium Webdriver example from the top of my head:

```
List<WebElement> elems = wd.getElements(By.class("class1"));
```

- Selenium Webdriver
- HtmlUnit